# Could someone explain this simple code to me please?

Tags: c#, binary

I just wanted to understand this bit of code.

```
static int convert2binary(int Decimal)
{
    int remainder, final = 0;
    string result = "";
    bool NaN;

    while (Decimal > 0)
    {
        remainder = Decimal % 2;
        Decimal /= 2;
        result = remainder + result;
        NaN = int.TryParse(result, out final);
    }
    return final;
}
```

It's a binary converter, how does it work exactly? I just don't get the modulus, decimal /= 2 and then plus them both together, how does that give binary?

Comment: Take a piece of paper and pen, take a number work on that. Let us know when you struck and what you have tried.

Comment: ugh, thats the autocorrect, dont mind that

Comment: @balls: please post code that actually compiles.

Comment: http://www.helpwithpcs.com/courses/binary-numbers.htm

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: I'm also sorry to be a complete pedant, but the code actually compiles. _Yes_, it is definitely lousy naming of variables, but it is allowed.

Comment: @Nailuj: What about using the `+` operator on an integer and a string?

Comment: Given that the input is an int and the output is *also* an int, I found this code to be rather confusing. It may have been more clear if the result was a string.  (Also? The var named Decimal isn't necessarily a decimal number -- it is just an int, which is just a number that can be formatted to be displayed as a hex or octal or binary number, but is intrinsically none of these on its own.)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: using the `+` operator on an int and a string isn't perhaps the best coding practice either. But it is still allowed (`Console.WriteLine("str" + 1);` will output `str1`).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: That's not a problem.

Comment: @Nailuj: Oops, I stand corrected.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: no problem, I'll even keep you company! I enjoy standing next to people standing corrected ;-)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan "final" is not a keyword.

Comment: @phoog - it is... albeit in a completely different language - lol (trudges off for a long nap)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan true enough; perhaps I should have said "'final' is not a keyword in this scope because it is not a keyword in C#"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just input some data, OK?

```
convert2binary(10)
-> remainder, final = 0
-> result = ""
-> NaN (= false)

loop:
Decimal > 0, so: remainder = Decimal % 2 (= 0) and Decimal /= 2 ( = 5)
result = remainder + result = 0 + ""
NaN = false
repeat:
Decimal > 0, so: remainder = Decimal % 2 (= 1) and Decimal /= 2 ( = 2)
result = remainder + result = "10"
NaN = false
repeat:
Decimal > 0, so: remainder = Decimal % 2 (= 0) and Decimal /= 2 ( = 1)
result = remainder + result = "010"
NaN = false
repeat:
Decimal > 0, so: remainder = Decimal % 2 (= 1) and Decimal /= 2 ( = 0)
result = remainder + result = "1010"
NaN = false
repeat: WHOOPS: Decimal == 0, so we return the final (int representation) of result.
```

Now, why does this work?

Basically, on each iteration, you split off the last binary digit from the right of your number (this is the `%2` bit). Since you then divide the rest by 2 (the `/=2` bit), you can do this in a loop.

Each iteration will give you a successive position in the numbers polynom:

```
decimal(10) == 1 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0 = binary(1010)
```

You can go in the other direction too: If you wanted to write an `int.ToString()` method for printing out the decimal variant of the number, you would split off the last digit with `% 10` (the remainder of dividing the number by ten) and that is the rightest-most digit to print. Divide the rest by 10 to so you can repeat for the tens position, the hundreds position etc...

lets try this out!

```
int number = 123;
// this is equivalent to: (1 * 10^2) + (2 * 10^1) + (3 * 10^0)
int remainder = number % 10; // remainder = 3
number /= 10 // number = 12 (integer division!!)
result = remainder + ""; // result = "3"
// number is now: (1 * 10^1) + (2 * 10^0), because we divided by 10!
remainder = number % 10; // remainder = 2
number /= 10 // number = 1
result = remainder + result; // result = "23"
// number is now: (1 * 10^0)
remainder = number % 10; // remainder = 1
number /= 10 // number = 0 - we're going to STOP now!
result = remainder + result; // result = "123"
// yay! hurray!!
```

So, you see, your number system (be it binary or octal or decimal or hexadecimal or whatever) is just shorthand for writing down a polynom of powers of your base. The right-most digit is always base^0, and the exponent increases by one for each digit you move left.

Bonus points if you figure out what the decimal point does ;)

Answer (score 0):

See the second method on this page: http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary

This is what your algorithm is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

When converting between decimal and binary, remember that each binary digit is a a power of 2 in decimal.

> 100110 = 1*2^5 + 0*2^4 + 0*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^0 = 38

So to build the binary string from an integer, starting from the right:

- Take the modulus of the decimal number and 2 (the remainder of your number divided by 2)
- Append the result to the left of your binary string
- Divide your number by 2
- Repeat until entire number is processed

Finally convert that string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

> `100110 = 1*2^5 + 0*2^4 + 0*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^0 = 38`

a ***MUCH*** cleaner way to think of that would be

---

```
2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(+1)+0)+0)+1)+1)+0 = 38
```

---

place all copies of the base on left side, and split the big-endian numeric string, one digit per layer, on right side.

This way it's easier to see the original `100110` in the new representation, while avoiding duplicative work, as each inner layer benefits from multiplications previously done

adapting a similar approach, certain merseene primes could also be expressed in this framework :

```
      2^(2^(2)-1)-1       => 2^(3)-1 | 7
   2^(2^(2^(2)-1)-1)-1    => 2^(7)-1 | 127
2^(2^(2^(2^(2)-1)-1)-1)-1 => 2^127-1 | 170141183460469231731687303715884105727
```

as well as generic powers of 2

(the `+0` are superfluous but included to make them comparable to above):

```
2^(2^(2^(2^(2)-1)+0)+1)+0 => 2^257 =>  231584178474632390847141970017375815706
                                       539969331281128078915168015826259279872
```

and **binary squaring** algorithm becomes just :

```
2*(2*(2*(2*(2)^2)^2)^2)^2-1 =      2147483647 = (3-1)^31-1
3*(3*(3*(3*(3)^2)^2)^2)^2-4 = 617673396283943 =   (3)^31-3-1
```

or say `6 ^ 61` - 61 has bin-string representation of :

```
   big-endian | 111101 
little-endian | 101111
```

and their corresponding binary squaring expression becomes

```
293242067884135544935936513642647623193965101056
293242067884135544935936513642647623193965101056
    # gawk profile, created Wed Aug 23 13:38:49 2023

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
  1     print (((((6) ^ 2 * 6) ^ 2 * 6) ^ 2 * 6) ^ 2 * 1) ^ 2 * 6
  1     print 6 * (1 * (6 * (6 * (6 * (6) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2
    }
```